# How to add button next to Add User button in Django Admin Site

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I am working on Django Project where I need to extract the list of user to excel from the Django Admin's Users Screen. I added `actions` variable to my Sample Class for getting the CheckBox before each user's id.

```
class SampleClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions =[make_published]
```

Action make_published is already defined. Now I want to append another button next to `Add user` button as shown in fig.  [image: Admin User Screen]. But I dont know how can I achieve this this with out using new template. I want to use that button for printing selected user data to excel. Thanks, please guide me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Create a template in you template folder: admin/YOUR_APP/YOUR_MODEL/change_list.html
2. Put this into that template

   ```
   {% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
   {% block object-tools-items %}

       {{ block.super }}

       <li>
           <a href="export/" class="grp-state-focus addlink">Export</a>
       </li>

   {% endblock %}
   ```
3. Create a view function in `YOUR_APP/admin.py` and secure it with annotation

   ```
   from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

   @staff_member_required
   def export(self, request):

       ... do your stuff ...

       return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"])
   ```
4. Add new url into `YOUR_APP/admin.py` to url config for admin model

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

   class YOUR_MODELAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

       ... list def stuff ...

       def get_urls(self):
           urls = super(MenuOrderAdmin, self).get_urls()
           my_urls = patterns("",
               url(r"^export/$", export)
           )
           return my_urls + urls
   ```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: I followed up until the last part, where is url(r"^ financial-export/$) coming from?

Comment: Your link has two `class` attributes: `class="grp-state-focus" class="addlink"`

Comment: Thanks you, fixedd.

Comment: for me, I had to put change_list.html in APP/templates/admin/APP/MODEL/change_list.html

Comment: How to access model queryset from the view?

Answer (score 0):

The *easy* and *accepted* way is to override the template.

If you don't want to mess with the Django templates, you could add a `Media` class to your admin and add some javascript to create the button although I think creating elements with javascript is a bit nasty and should be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Though other answers are entirely valid, I think it is important to note that it is absolutely not necessary to add a button to get such behavior. You can use admin actions, as you did for the `make_published` action.

This as the advantage of not requiring to override any template, and thus prevent from potential troubles when upgrading django version (as admin templates may change, and changes might not be "compatible" with the way you overrode it).

```
import csv

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import timezone

def export_as_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta
    filename = format(timezone.now(), "{app}_{model}-%Y%m%d_%H%M.csv").format(
        app=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    field_names = [f.get_attname() for f in opts.concrete_fields]
    writer.writerow(field_names)
    for obj in queryset.only(*field_names):
        writer.writerow([str(getattr(obj, f)) for f in field_names])

    return response
```

Admin actions are made for this, adding a custom button is one step closer to "over-customization", which means it's probably time to write your own views.

> The admin has many hooks for customization, but beware of trying to use those hooks exclusively. If you need to provide a more process-centric interface that abstracts away the implementation details of database tables and fields, then it’s probably time to write your own views.

*Quote from the [introduction paragraph of Django Admin's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/)*