# Create an estimator tool in Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django. I have read the official documentations and managed to create models in Django. I have a task to create an estimator tool that could provide the estimate(cost) to the user when he selects the hardware/softwares etc. This could be something similar to this http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html. This is only for reference but I want to add details dynamically. 
Basically I am curious to know about:

1. How to add rows in Django?
2. How is the 'Monthly cost' working in amazon calculator? 
   I want to achieve something similar to this dynamic estimations. 
   Any pointers/articles/suggestions will be helpful in my learning and analysis.

Comment: So what you're saying is, "Can't edit object in django admin page"? Did I understand right?

Comment: what do you need complete project architecture?

Comment: Yes @Beomi, thats correct. Is there a library I need for that?

Comment: No, No. By default, admin page allows editing. but as you say so, would you upload `models.py` and `admin.py` file in question? there may be `readonly` attribute on it.

Comment: @amankumar, no I dont need project architecture but any tutorial or models in python that I can use in this scenario.

Comment: Django admin already provide the CRUD operations.

Comment: @Beomi, I see that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the Django admin template for that.

[How to add button next to Add User button in Django Admin Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968781/how-to-add-button-next-to-add-user-button-in-django-admin-site)

for auto-selecting the group value you can use

https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects

Comment: ok, can you tell me how is estimate happening here http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html? When you select type, you see the monthly cost changing. How is that happening?